# Cache Geospatial calculations or calculate on the fly?

Tags: caching, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2008-r2, geospatial

I'm a developer on a service vehicle dispatching web app. It's written in .Net 4+, MVC4, using SQL server.

There are 2000+ locations stored in the database as geography data-types. Assuming we send resources from location A to location B, the drive time / distance etc... needs to be displayed at one point. If I calculate the distance with SQL Server's STDistance it will only give me the "As the crow flies" distance. So the system will need to hit a geo spatial service like bing, Google, or ESRI and get the actual drive time or suggested routes. the problem is this is a core function and will happen ALOT.

Should I pre-populate a lookup table with pre-calculated distances or average drive times? The down side is even without adding more locations that's 4Million records to search every time the information is needed.

On top of this, most times the destination is not one of our stored geospatial coordinates and can instead be an address or long/lat point anywhere on the continent which makes pre-calculating impossible.

I'm trying to avoid performance issues having to hit some geoservies endpoint constantly.

Any suggestions on how best to approach this?

-thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked at these problems before, you are unlikely to be able to store them all.

1. it is usually against almost all of the routing providers TOS for you to cache the results. You can sometimes negotiate this ability but it costs alot.
2. Given that there is not a fixed set of points you are searching against, doing one calculation gives you little information for the next calculation.

I would say maybe you can store the route for pair once they have been selected so you can show that route again if needed. Once the transaction is done I would remove the route from your DB.

If you really want to cache all this or have more control over it you can use PGRouting (with Postgresql) and then obtain street data. though I doubt it is worth your effort.